# How to utilize a local file in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I am creating a docker container that has a script that will run and give some output but in order to do so it needs to use the information from the .env file. However, the catch is this file changes frequently so it cannot be inside the container when built. I am aware of mounting and volumes but new to docker and having trouble. Here is my

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD main.py .

RUN pip install requests python-dotenv

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

I have built this doing

```
docker build -t dataset .
```

Now I have the issue of needing to use the .env file and tried to follow the documentation and came up with this to run it

```
docker run -v /Users/alexrobey/Documents/github/datasets:/tmp datasets
```

The `dockerfile` and `main.py` are on the root directory and I have created a /tmp folder that has the .env file in it. Is this the right way to do everything? I am getting an application error that makes me believe I have done something the wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you run this application in a Python virtual environment, instead of a Docker container?  That will be able to directly access files on the host without doing any special setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program can read directly environment variables you can use the `--env-file` argument with docker run :

`docker run --env-file <path_to_env_file> ...`

Or perhaps you can use `--mount` argument to mount your temporary file.

`docker run --mount source=/<source_path>,target=<target_path> ...` (cf : https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount )